# Enzyme - testing restricted route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, enzyme, jestjs

So I created a `RestrictedRoute` component based on `Route` from `react-router (v4)` and using `branch` method from `recompose`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose, branch, renderComponent } from 'recompose';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const RestrictedRoute = (props) => {
  const { component, ...otherProps } = props;
  return <Route {...otherProps} component={component} />;
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  authenticated: state.authentication.session,
});
const branched = branch(
  ({ authenticated }) => !authenticated,
  renderComponent(() => <Redirect to="/" />),
);

const enhanced = compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  branched,
)(RestrictedRoute);

export default enhanced;
```

It works perfectly fine but now I need to write some tests that will tell me if the redirect is working properl, so I did this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Redirect, MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import RestrictedRoute from '../RestrictedRoute';
import { initialAuthenticationState } from 'Reducers/authentication';

describe('<RestrictedRoute />', () => {
  const mockStore = configureStore();
  let store;
  let container;
  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore({
      authentication: { ...initialAuthenticationState }, // authentication.session is false in the initialAuthenticationState
    });
    container = shallow(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <RestrictedRoute />
        </Provider>,
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
  })
  test('redirects if not authenticated', () => {
    expect(container.find(Redirect).length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

I get the following results, which is not what I expected:

```
● <RestrictedRoute /> › redirects if not authenticated

    expect(received).toBe(expected)

    Expected value to be (using ===):
      1
    Received:
      0
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with the `shallow`. I shouldn't have used it because it is not its purpose. `mount` was the function I was looking for.